# jquery how to know checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rh74h/

The checkboxes are these

```
<div ID="campaignDiv" runat="server">
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="textDropdown">Text1</span> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" /> 
        <label for="1"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="textDropdown">Text1</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" />
        <label for="2"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="textDropdown">Text1</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3" />
        <label for="3"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="textDropdown">Text1</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="4" />
        <label for="4"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Because I am using a specif style, I am not able to know which checkbox is selected an which is not.

Actaully I need the `value` of the checkboxes.

how please?

#### If it were a simple checkbox, I would be able to do that in jquery, but sorry in this style i don't

[image]

Comment: in fact there is a default/standard checkbox input field in each styled one, so how could not you get its value?

Comment: @KingKing I could get the value easily, but I don't know which one is selected and which one is not. please check the jsfiddle to check my purpose. I am able to get the value of all checkboxes, but not the value of selected checkboxes

Comment: Have a look at second example on http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ . Does it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be over-thinking this one. If I understand your requirements, this should work just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the value of checked checkboxes within the campaignDiv
    var checkedValues = $("#campaignDiv input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    console.log(checkedValues);
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/rh74h/2/).

**EDIT: Additional Example**

Alternatively, you can attach to the change event of the checkboxes and retrieve the value then. Whether or not you have explicitly specified `checked=''` or not, the property is implicit in the `input` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the value of checked checkboxes within the campaignDiv
    $("#campaignDiv input:checkbox").change(function() {
        var checkedValues = $("#campaignDiv input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        console.log(checkedValues);
    });
});
```

Here's [another fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/Y2h8U/).

Comment: in your example, you added the `checked` property to the checkbox, right?

Comment: I am not over-thinking in it. the problem still existed which is there is no `checked` property. that is why I am asking

Comment: Correct, else there would be nothing in `checkedValues`.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, see updated example and fiddle. Does that address your concern?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, whether you explicitly set the `checked` property is irrelevant.

Comment: I made a simple edit to your jfiddle by adding a button to check the result, and it works like the majec. please tell me how is it working though there is no `checked` property? you are super excellent. +1 will accept the answer when system allwos http://jsfiddle.net/Y2h8U/3/

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, whether you specify the checked property or not, it still belongs to the object. Read up on the `input` tag for further info on its properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rh74h/5/

get value for each checked item

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var checked = $("#campaignDiv input:checkbox:checked");
    if(checked.length > 0){
        $.each(checked,function(val,elem){
            alert($(elem).attr('value'););
        })
    }

});
```

Comment: At least switch up my comment an syntax a bit so the copy/paste isn't so obvious.

Comment: There, that's better!

Comment: if you see I have posted exactly your code. I was wrong, take different tab in my browser. I was watching your example and decide to offer another solution @JamesHill